# Starting JSF project with Eclipse

Tags: java, eclipse, jsf

i whant to ask, if there is simple way to start clean JSF project in Eclipse? I mean, so preoject with configuration and sample data?

I need something like Matt Raible's App Fuse, but created for Eclipse, Ivy and Jboss server

Answer (score 1):

The simplest way is to

- Download Glassfish 3.0.1 and install it.
- Download Eclipse Java EE
- In Eclipse, goto Help -> Eclipse Marketplace and install the Oracle Enterprise Pack for Eclipse
- Create new web application using Glassfish as the server.

It is much easier with the Netbeans bundled with Glassfish.

Answer (score 0):

You can try something like Matt Raible's App Fuse, if that's what you have in mind.

With configuration and data?  No.  How do you expect Eclipse or anything else to read your mind?